# Distorted java apps

Tags: java, linux, fonts, system

Since I removed my `.java` and `.gradle` directories from home and restarted my linux box today, all **java applications with Gui** looks distorted. No texts appear where they normally do and most input fields are over-sized with also no fonts set. This make all my java apps unusable.

**A clean install of Jdk7&8 took no effect! I did no java related system updates.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there was something important in those directories.

Comment: Font-settings, maybe. But they were recreated.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but why did you delete those directories?

Comment: Because I had some issues with gradle during development and wanted to start again with a clean environment.